# Parsing JSON using jq or Python

Tags: json, linux, unix, jq

I have this nested JSON

```
[
  "[[Input=[Name=ABC, createDateTime=2019-30-11, RollNumber=9]]]",
  "[[SubjectList=[Summer=, Winter=, Autumn=, Spring=, rList=, sList=, additionalList=, emailList=, FoodList=, sAssignmentList=, summerworkList=, outdoorList=, movielist=]]]",
  "[ProcessingDate=2018-10-06]",
  "[Hobbies=Football]",
  "[Phone=Android,,]"
]
```

How can I process this JSON and get the value football or rollnumber using  Python?

This is what I tried:

Code

```
import json
row = '''[
  "[[Input=[Name=ABC, createDateTime=2019-30-11, RollNumber=9]]]",
  "[[SubjectList=[Summer=, Winter=, Autumn=, Spring=, rList=, sList=, additionalList=, emailList=, FoodList=, sAssignmentList=, summerworkList=, outdoorList=, movielist=]]]",
  "[ProcessingDate=2018-10-06]",
  "[Hobbies=Football]",
  "[Phone=Android,,]"
]'''
row_dict = json.loads(row)
print(row_dict[3])
```

Using this - I get following output:

> [Hobbies=Football]

But I am missing next level parsing to get just **football** as output

Comment: Are `Input, SubjectList,ProcessingDate, Hobbies, Phone` supposed to be json key and value format?

Comment: The main list is a JSON array, but the contents of the strings are a format I've never seen before, you'll need to write a custom parser for them. Why not make it all JSON?

Comment: hello Barmar, I have edited my question. I am a newbie so may be have lot to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses [`capture`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#capture(val),capture(regex;flags)) on the non-json strings in the array.
It assumes the [`[:alnum:]`](https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/pcre) posix regex character class suffices to match the values after the =
Sample execution assuming data in `test.json`

```
$ jq -M '.[] | capture("Hobbies=(?<Hobbies>[[:alnum:]]+)")' test.json
{
  "Hobbies": "Football"
}
```

Here is a variation which produces exactly `Football`:

```
$ jq -Mr '.[] | capture("Hobbies=(?<Hobbies>[[:alnum:]]+)") | .Hobbies' test.json
Football
```

Here's an example script which uses multiple captures and combines them with [`add`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#add)

```
[ .[]
  |  capture("Hobbies=(?<Hobbies>[[:alnum:]]+)")
   , capture("RollNumber=(?<RollNumber>[[:alnum:]]+)")
] | add
```

Sample execution assuming script in `test.jq`

```
$ jq -M -f test.jq test.json
{
  "RollNumber": "9",
  "Hobbies": "Football"
}
```